# Symlink npm to pnpm

Tags: node.js, npm

My understanding is that `pnpm` is designed to be a drop-in replacement for `npm`. However, I'm not sure if this is true for all cases.

Is it safe to just delete `npm` and symlink in `pnpm` or will that break stuff?

Comment: Maybe you need ask this question in stackoverflow.com, not unix.stackexchange.com.